# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't locate interior point for polygon

Tags: java, geotiff

I am getting error while using Geo Tiff for vectoring my image

```
//vectorization
System.out.println("vectorization starts");
GridCoverage2D srcCoverage = new GeoTiffReader(new File("E:/output/sometiffile.TIFF")).read(new GeneralParameterValue[]{policy, gridsize, useJaiRead});
SimpleFeatureCollection fc = RasterToVectorProcess.process(srcCoverage, 0, cov.getEnvelope(), Collections.singletonList(0.0d), true, null);
System.out.println("process ends");
MapContext map = new DefaultMapContext();
map.setTitle("raster to vector conversion");
Style style = SLD.createPolygonStyle(Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, 1.0f);
map.addLayer(fc, style);
JMapFrame.showMap(map);
System.out.println("vectorization ends");
```

Output

```
vectorization starts
adding...
adding...
adding...
adding...
adding...
adding...
adding...
Exception in thread "main" org.geotools.process.ProcessException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't locate interior point for polygon
    at org.geotools.process.raster.RasterToVectorProcess.convert(RasterToVectorProcess.java:385)
    at org.geotools.process.raster.RasterToVectorProcess.process(RasterToVectorProcess.java:310)
    at com.rgb.PixelExtractor.extract(PixelExtractor.java:347)
    at com.rgb.RGBSpliter.main(RGBSpliter.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't locate interior point for polygon
    at org.geotools.process.raster.RasterToVectorProcess.assembleFeatures(RasterToVectorProcess.java:452)
    at org.geotools.process.raster.RasterToVectorProcess.convert(RasterToVectorProcess.java:380)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: It is look like that you image contains some feature that too small. Wild guess: try to reduce grid size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" org.geotools.process.ProcessException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't locate interior point for polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39117354/exception-in-thread-main-org-geotools-process-processexception-java-lang-ille)

Comment: I reversed the duplicate link @DenisKurochkin as this one, at least, has an answer, when the other had no activity.

Comment: I need to delete that question because of ''s''e''x in Proces'' s ''exeption. My proxy server says that page is prohibited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add bands

```
 SimpleFeatureCollection fc = RasterToVectorProcess.process(srcCoverage, 3, cov.getEnvelope(), Collections.singletonList(0.0d), true, null);
```